# Increase log level in Apache2 logs

Tags: apache, http, logging, apache2, httpd.conf

I am trying to load a loapost module in Apache2 server. However, I keep getting one line errors. I would like to get a better view of the http logs in order to find out why the error has occurred.

How can I increase the log level of http logs in Apache2? I would like to set the log level to 200.

Thanks

Comment: You could always take a **drastic and novel** approach and [read the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel)

Comment: Who keeps upvoting poor questions????